# How to build Ubuntu Touch in 32-bit computer

Tags: 64-bit, ubuntu-touch, compiling, 32-bit

I was trying to port Ubuntu Touch for my HTC Incredible S.
I had setup the source code and drivers.
During build, I am getting error that the build can be executed only on 64-bit computer.

When I searched for my laptop model spec, I found that it is 32-bit.
What is the restriction in building on 32-bit machine?
Is there a possibility to build it on 32-bit.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It does appear that at this moment in time, it is not possible to build using a 32-bit system. Development tools are currently available for 64-bit: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Building

> For development you can run any 64-bit Desktop version of Ubuntu
>   between 12.04 LTS and 13.04.

Comment: is there work going on to support 32-bit build environment please?

Comment: @Viveak I'd be lying if I said I knew.